# Python: Using a counter to refer to a variable

Tags: python

I hacked out a script that works, but I'm trying to find a tidier way to do it.

In its simplest form, I have two modules: definitions and script.

'definitions' has a list of variables, like so:

```
input0 = 5
input1 = 6
input2 = 4
```

My goal is to set up raspberrypi GPIO inputs, but the definitions file is managed by someone else. So I cannot change these `inputX` syntax.

'script' refers to that those variables, like so:

```
import definitions
list = [1,2,3]

if len(list) > 1:
   print(definitions.input0)
if len(list) > 2:
   print(definitions.input1)
if len(list) > 3:
   print(definitions.input2)
```

but I would like to simplify my script to something along the lines of:

```
import definitions
list = [1,2,3]

def setup(list):
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(list)):
        print(definitions.input[index])
        index = index + 1
```

This results in an attribute error: 'module' has not attribute 'input'.

I'm not sure how to phrase a search question, is there a way to refer to the variables in 'definitions' iteratively?

Comment: Why do you *have* separate variables in `definitions`? Why not use a list?

Comment: Write your `input` variables in a list instead of in separate variables.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python list", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Also, naming all your variables that hold lists `list` is a bad idea, because the `list` type has dibs on that name.

Comment: It isn't really named 'list' this is really simplified

Comment: I suggest that you work through a tutorial on printing the elements of a list.

Comment: @user2357112: the problem with it is really that `list` *doesn't* have dibs. If you shadow it with another variable using the same name, you can't get at the builtin any more!

Comment: in `definitions` create a dictionary  `defines = {1: ..., m 2:...., 3: ....}` in `script` : `for i in range(1,4): print(defines.get(i,"") )` to get them ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner  That's what I thought, but I was hoping that there was a way to leave 'definitions' unchanged, I have this script pair rolled out in a few places that are in already in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please don't assign your data to `list`. It is the name of the `list` class and overwriting it can only introduce confusion.

To your question,

```
print(definitions.input[index])
```

doesn't work because `definitions.input` is not a list and in fact, do not exist at all. But

```
print(getattr(definitions, "input"+str(index)))
```

will work, as long as `"input"+str(index)` evaluates to `input0` or alike that exists.

Comment: Thanks, but that evaluates to input0 and I would like it to evaluate to 5

Comment: @Virgilio you should try running the whole line of code…  if you've set your files up as you say it'll just work

Comment: Yes, thanks both of you for pointing that out.  I mistakenly used Adrian's "input", but my real definitions file uses different names!

Comment: Adrian provided the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do something like that (what your exact goal is a little unclear):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
// script.py

import definitions
Sequence = [1,2,3]

def setup(sequence):
    for key in sequence:
        print(key, getattr(definitions, f'input{key - 1}', 'None'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(Sequence)
```

Comment: Thank you Travis,  I like that way too.  My goal is to set up raspberrypi GPIO inputs, but the definitions file is managed by someone else. So I'm going to try this, instead of a print line, with an appropriate GPIO.setup statement using your suggested getattr() function, i've never used it before!

Comment: I think if you had described this use case in your original question, you wouldn't have seen the downvoting that you did.

Comment: The two "pieces" of the solution above are recognizing that you can use `getattr` on a module and how to do `f'{}'` format strings.